# Limit of Mahlo cardinals

Tags: set-theory, large-cardinals

What cardinal is the limit of this fundamental sequence?

{The first Mahlo cardinal, the first 1-Mahlo cardinal, the first hyper-Mahlo cardinal, the first hyper-hyper-Mahlo cardinal, the first hyper-hyper-hyper-Mahlo cardinal, ...}

where the definition of a $\alpha$-Mahlo cardinal is as follows:

If we define a function where $\psi_0(\lambda)$ is the $\lambda$th ($\alpha$-1)-Mahlo cardinal, then the fixed points of $\psi_0$ are the α-Mahlo cardinals, and the 0-Mahlo cardinals are just the Mahlo cardinals.

Thanks!

**EDIT:** Based on comments, I have a new easier to understand question:

What is the name of the first cardinal that has the properties of being Mahlo, hyper-Mahlo, hyper-hyper-Mahlo, hyper-hyper-hyper-Mahlo, hyper-hyper-hyper-hyper-Mahlo, and so on?

Comment: What is the length of the sequence?

Comment: It's a fundamental sequence, so it has ω entries.

Comment: Ok. So, what kind of answer do you expect beyond the description you have given?

Comment: Well, another description is the first cardinal that is Mahlo, hyper-Mahlo, hyper-hyper-Mahlo, hyper-hyper-hyper-Mahlo, hyper-hyper-hyper-hyper-Mahlo, etc. going on forever.

Comment: The name of the first cardinal with those properties.

Comment: @Plasmath "another description is the first cardinal that is Mahlo, hyper-Mahlo, hyper-hyper-Mahlo, hyper-hyper-hyper-Mahlo, hyper-hyper-hyper-hyper-Mahlo, etc. going on forever. " Not if that sequence has length $\omega$: the limit of such a sequence isn't even regular, let alone a large cardinal.

Comment: I think that I'm wording it badly. Here's what I meant:
What is the name of the first cardinal that is Mahlo, hyper-Mahlo, hyper-hyper-Mahlo, hyper-hyper-hyper-Mahlo, hyper-hyper-hyper-hyper-Mahlo, ...?

Comment: I don't believe that has a special name.

Comment: If "going on forever" in one comment and "$\dots$"  another just mean $\omega$ steps, then I'd probably call this "hyper${}^\omega$-Mahlo, but I don't think that's commonly understood, so if I used it in a paper I'd include a definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is some problems with definitions here.

1. **The definition you use** of $\alpha+1$-Mahlo cardinals is a cardinal $\kappa$ such that $\kappa$ is the $\kappa$th $\alpha$-Mahlo cardinal.

   **This is not the standard definition**. Usually, a cardinal is said to be $\alpha+1$-Mahlo if $\{\beta\lt\kappa|\beta\text{ is }\alpha\text{-Mahlo}\}$ is **stationary**.

   We will call the first notion $\alpha$-Mahlo, and the second notion $\alpha$-Mahlo* (**You will never find that notation in literature, I just wanted to clarify which definition I am using**)

   If $\kappa$ is $\alpha$-Mahlo* for $\alpha\gt 0$, then $\kappa$ is $\alpha$-Mahlo, $\alpha+1$-Mahlo, $\kappa$-Mahlo, and so on.
2. If we say that $\kappa$ is hyper-Mahlo if $\kappa$ is $\kappa$-Mahlo, and then define $\alpha+1$-hyper-Mahlo cardinals as fixed points of $\alpha$-hyper-Mahlo cardinals, hyper$^2$-Mahlo as $\kappa$-hyper-Mahlo cardinals, and so on, then we can get the notion of $\alpha$-hyper$^n$-Mahlo cardinals.

   I should stress that **this is not the standard definition**, but it appears to be the one you are using.

   Normally, we say that $\kappa$ is hyper-Mahlo* if $\kappa$ is $\kappa$-Mahlo*, and then define $\alpha+1$-hyper-Mahlo* cardinals as **stationary limits** of $\alpha$-hyper-Mahlo* cardinals, hyper$^2$-Mahlo* as $\kappa$-hyper-Mahlo cardinals*, and so on.

   If $\kappa$ is $1$-Mahlo*, then $\kappa$ is hyper-Mahlo, hyper$^2$-Mahlo, hyper$^3$-Mahlo, and so on.
3. The first cardinal $\kappa$ that is hyper$^n$-Mahlo for every $n\lt\omega$, is not the same as  the cardinal $\kappa'=\text{sup}\{\text{The least Mahlo cardinal, the least hyper-Mahlo cardinal, the least hyper}^2\text{-Mahlo cardinal...}\}$

   $\kappa'$ has cofinality $\omega$, and so is not even inaccessible, and  $\kappa'\lt\kappa$.

There is no official name for $\kappa'$. You could call $\kappa$ the least hyper$^\omega$-Mahlo cardinal, but **don't forget that the definition you are using of hyper$^n$-Mahlo cardinals is not the standard one!** If you use the standard definition, using stationary limits instead of fixed points, then $\kappa$ would be the least hyper$^\omega$-Mahlo cardinal.